# How can I replace within a SELECT the statement from one table to ther other one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I am trying to SELECT two tables an replace from table A an attribute of a value from table B.
Importants is for me that the tables not updated.

***table_A***

```
id  category_id filename
1   2   apple
2   12  banana
3   453 pineapple
```

***table_B***

```
id  category_color  category_type
2   red fruit
12  yellow  fruit
453 brown   fruit
```

The MYSQL version is 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.category_id = table_B.id SET table_A.category_id = category_name;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET table_A.category_id = category_name' at line 1
```

The output should like the below example

***output***

```
id  category_id filename
1   red apple
2   yellow  banana
3   brown   pineapple
```

Comment: What is the `SET` for???  You are `SELECT`ing records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET` doesn't belong in a `SELECT` query. Instead, reference the value from the second table in the field list:

```
SELECT A.id, B.category_name, A.filename 
FROM table_A A 
INNER JOIN table_B B ON A.category_id = B.id
```

Output

```
id  filename    category_name
1   apple       red
2   banana      yellow
3   pineapple   brown
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jBW3AewZhQvaBzzEYXkmoF/0)